# Click event doesn't fire when parsing external html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a project where I need to load html from an external file and add it to an existing div element. 
It works great, except that the *.click()* events never fire when clicking on the desired icon in the generated html.

**Code that loads the html**:

```
$.each(data, function (index, review) {
    let html = $.parseHTML($.trim(review));

    $(html).appendTo($items);
});
```

Root element of the loaded html is a class named "*lc-rating-wrap*".

**The js that doesn't fire on click**:

```
$(".lc-rating-wrap > .vote-wrap > .do-vote-wrap > .icon").click(function () {
    //doStuff
});
```

I guess it has something to do with that the elements isnt there when I load the js file? 
Am I using *parseHTML()* correctly?

Comment: Since the elements are loaded dynamically, you could use: `'$(document).on('click', ".lc-rating-wrap > .vote-wrap > .do-vote-wrap > .icon"), function() {
    //doStuff
});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your content is dynamic, but your event is binded only for existing elements. Change it to be `$(static).on(event, dynamic, callback)`:

```
$(document).on('click', ".lc-rating-wrap > .vote-wrap > .do-vote-wrap > .icon", function () {
    //doStuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use delegate instead click.

```
$( "#parent" ).delegate( ".icon", "click", function() {
   //dostuff
});
```

Parent is a element which you using to generate your elements (inside).
So it cannot be generated dynamicaly.

Comment: Justinas' answer is the equivalent for modern jQuery, but that sounds right.

Comment: I used this in some older jquery versions. before that was function called live. But was removed some time ago. I wasnt sure if on function will detect dynamic elements, but good to know :)

Answer (score 0):

use jquery click event delegation. see https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Bind event to an parent element already found in your page when js is binding click event. Use .on("click", "your selector", function(){})